# A question related to Dimensions & Spanning of square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a span of square matrix of order $n$. $W$ be a subspace of matrices with entries in each row adding upto zero. Then $dimW =$ ?.
The option given are:

  a. $n$

  b. $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

  c. $n-1$

  d. $n (n-1)$

I guess the answer is $n$. Because dimension of space of which $W$ is subspace is 3. So subspace $W$ must have same dimension inspite of any information. Am I right? I am un under graduate student, not a mathematician. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that the space where $W$ is a subspace is $3$? And also $dim W \leq dim(\text{space where $W$ is a subspace})$

Comment: A great favor from you. Thanks a lot for editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you really mean that $V$ is the space of square matrices of order $n$. In that case the dimension of $W$ is $n(n-1)$.

Edit: In any row, the first $(n-1)$ elements you can choose arbitrarily, the last one gets determined by them. You do it for each row, hence dimension becomes $n(n-1)$. Explicitly the basis can be given by the matrices $E^{pq}$, for $1 \le p \le n, 1 \le q \le n-1$, where $E^{pq}_{ij} = 1$ if $(i,j) = (p,q)$ and $E^{pq}_{ij} = -1$ if $(i,j) = (p, n)$ and rest are zero.

Comment: Will you try to explain how it comes to be n(n-1) ?

Comment: See edit. Does that help you?

Comment: May I know what criteria you have used to determine the dimension? Your more little  help will make my concepts more clear.

Comment: i told you the basis right? How many basis elements are there? The number of basis elements is equal to dimension. Clearly there are n(n-1) basis elements which have been explicitly demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

if every row in $W$ sums to zero, then $W v = 0$ where v is a column vector with entries of $[1,1,...,1]$

The kernel of W is non-trivial.

The dimension of $W$ is less then $n.$

It could be considerably less then $n,$ but how much less cannot be determined by the information given.  We only know for sure of one vector in the kernel.

$dim(W)\le n-1$

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is unsatisfactory. In the question, I do not understand the role of $V$. As correctly mentioned in the previous answer, if the matrix w is in W then $w(v)=0$ for $v=(1...1).$ The question says that $W$ is A subspace and not THE subspace $W_1=\{w; w(v)=0\}.$ Therefore  $\dim W\leq \dim W_1=n(n-1).$  If you say THE subspace, the correct answer is d).